# trying to break apart a string in rust

Tags: rust

I have this string

```
abcdef x y z
```

or this one

```
"ab cd ef" x y z
```

I am trying to parse this in rust to

```
s1 = "abcdef"
arr =  ["x","y","z"]
```

or

```
s1 = "ab cd ef"
arr =  ["x","y","z"]
```

I tried the following (str is the starting string)

```
    let chars = str.chars().peekable();
    let s1:String = if *chars.peek().expect("value isnt empty") == '\"'{
        chars.skip(1).take_while(|c| *c!= '\"').collect()
    }else{
        chars.take_while(|c| *c!= ' ').collect()
    };

    let remainder_str = chars.collect::<String>();
    let remainder = remainder_str.split_whitespace();

    let mut arr: Vec<&OsStr> =
        remainder.map(|s| OsStr::new(s)).collect();
```

Ie create an iterator of the chars and walk it down the string pulling bits out as I go.

Doesnt work becuase the first collect eats 'chars'. I am sure I could do it via walking down the array of chars with an index inspecting each one in turn (aka, brute force) but that doesnt seem like idiomatic rust.

Can anybody suggest a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your idea taken to compilation:

```
fn doit(str: String) -> (String, Vec<String>) {
    let mut chars = str.chars().peekable();
    let s1:String = if *chars.by_ref().peek().expect("value isnt empty") == '\"'{
        chars.by_ref().skip(1).take_while(|c| *c!= '\"').collect()
    }else{
        chars.by_ref().take_while(|c| *c!= ' ').collect()
    };

    let remainder_str = chars.collect::<String>();
    let remainder = remainder_str.split_whitespace();

    let arr: Vec<String> =
        remainder.map(|s| s.to_string()).collect();
    (s1, arr)
}
```

`by_ref` is possibly your friend here.

Note, however, that this method is very likely *not* what you actually want, as it allocates stuff all over the place (all the `String`s, etc.).

You could be better off using only string slices that refer to the original string.

Comment: ty v much. rust is such an idiomatic language and yet its hard to find what they are. A real rust cookbook is whats called for.

Comment: and how would I do the slicing one. I would love to see it

Comment: The ingredients: Check if first character is quotes; if so, split the remaining string at the second quote and use `split` on the second part.